# How do you migrate questions from Math.se to Meta?

Tags: support, migration

I tried searching it in the search bar but I couldn't find any instructions on how to actually migrate a question.

Answer (score 5):

Flag a moderator; the link to do so is at the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 5):

If you have at least 3000 reputation, you can vote to close as "off topic" and the option of meta.math.SE should be one of the radio buttons.